# why does this work? Jquery, nextAll()

Tags: jquery

http://pastebin.com/x8ruGQFK

As you see, this is a very basic step by step "form".

This works perfectly, but why?

At the beginning i have 3 divs. then i set them hidden. then i set the first one on show.

then i click on next.

1. `var currentForm = $(".my-form-page:visible");`  i get the first div, which is visible.
2. `currentForm.hide();`  i hide it. yep, that's right. so again, everything is hidden.
3. `currentForm.nextAll(".my-form-page:first").show();` `nextAll`, would apply some css to all elements after it but since i have the pseudoclass `:first`, it wont. just on the first.

But since first applies just to visible elements, it shouldn't work. Why does this thing know, that the 2nd element, which is also hidden, is now the first? Why can i access it like that?

Comment: "`:first` applies only to visible elements" where did you get this idea?

Comment: uh i dont know, have read it somewhere. meaybe the meant first-child css pseudoclass. i dont know. so it is not? oaky thanks. but still, explaination eneded :)

Answer (score 2):

[`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) doesn't apply only to visible elements.  It is the equivalent of `:eq(0)`.  If you want it to apply only to visible elements you need to include the `:visible` selector again:

```
currentForm.nextAll(".my-form-page:visible:first").show();
```

Comment: i dont know :eq(0). im new, i dont udnerstand why it works. i just want to understand it fully

Comment: @xotix: it works because it's supposed to work.  `:first` selects the first matching element, in this case, the fist element with `.my-form-page`.

Comment: yeah and on each click the 2nd gets first and the 3 gets first. how? for me, the first div is the first div. thats something hardcoded. how can the last one be the first one?

Comment: @xotix: because you start with `var currentForm = $(".my-form-page:visible");`, which gets the currently visible form, which will be the 2nd on 2nd click, 3rd on 3rd, etc.  `nextAll` selects **only** the elements that follow that visible element and `:first` narrows it down to the first of those elements.  Instead of `nextAll`, you should just be using `next()` without `:first`.

Comment: ok thanks. i got it now, i think my problem was, that i thougth :first depens on the visibility. dont know why i thought that but yeah. thanks. so and another question ,how do i do a back button?

Comment: @xotix: you can use `history.back()` to go back a page.  If that doesn't help you, you might be better off asking a new question and elaborating a bit :-)